# Routing decoupling capacitors to a micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller, power, decoupling-capacitor, pcb-layers, routing

I'm attempting to design and make a Keyboard PCB and have stumbled onto a question I can't seem to find online (probably because I'm not searching for the right thing/lack of info)

When routing decoupling capacitors in parallel you do not place them next to one another, correct?
There should be one right next to every VCC pin?

ie. Not like this:
[image: Current PCB route]

But like this:
[image: New PCB route]

Per @Sparky256's suggestion here is the ground plane:
[image: Ground Plane]

Comment: yes, local to each power input pin.

Comment: Yes, not like that. The way you are showing it defeats the purpose of most of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally power supply bypass and signal filter caps get as close to the MCU body as possible. While the Vcc trace looks good the GND pads are linked with skinny traces that form a line from a via. If at all possible this GND should be a wide copper pour with many via's to a common ground plane.

As it is drawn the inductance will be high, thus noise on Vcc will be high at that location. Try to fatten the GND trace and see if extra via's can be inserted there. The many capacitors are good but not much use if not tied to ground plane in many places, for what little board space you have. When designing boards power and ground planes come first, then HF and high-impedance traces.

The bypass capacitors should be distributed so each Vcc pin has one next to it that has a short path to the ground plane.

Comment: I have updated the images, is it better now?

Comment: Profoundly better. Look at other CPU / MCU board layouts and they are much like yours.  With practice you will do this layout topology with ease. Yes, it means cramming SMD capacitors and Vcc and GND planes right up to the MCU body, but the performance gain is worth it.

Comment: Try to double or triple GND via's if they overlap a main ground plane on the bottom layer. This lowers inductance a lot, so capacitors are more effective.

Comment: Done (I think the ones I doubled are the ones you were referring to)

Comment: Very good, and yes you got it right. I assume the large ground pour is standalone and is not a small sub-set of the main ground plane, or you will have to "stitch" them together with tens of via's. Normally only ultra-fast CPU motherboards need such details.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate you taking some time to help me out :D

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, deco caps should be closest to the point of load, and on a micro with multiple power connections your caps should be adjacent each (in a perfect world).

The goal is to limit the stray inductance between source and load, in this case between the capacitor and the micro.